# Compilation fails: No such file or directory (but it DOES exist!)

Tags: go, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation, ethereum

I'm trying to compile the [Ethereum Go client](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum). Following [the instructions](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#building-the-source) I simply run `make geth`, but that fails:

```
$ make geth
build/env.sh go run build/ci.go install ./cmd/geth
make: build/env.sh: No such file or directory
make: *** [geth] Error 1
```

As far as I understand from this error it complaints that either `build/env.sh` or `build/ci.go` doesn't exist. So I checked out the build folder, but they both seem to be there:

```
$ ls -l build
total 648
drwxr-xr-x  3 kramer65  staff     102 Feb 13 13:45 _vendor
-rw-r--r--  1 kramer65  staff    2892 Feb 13 13:45 ci-notes.md
-rw-r--r--  1 kramer65  staff   30516 Feb 13 13:45 ci.go             <===
-rw-r--r--  1 kramer65  staff     123 Feb 13 13:45 deb.changelog
... some other files here
-rw-r--r--  1 kramer65  staff     379 Feb 13 13:45 deb.rules
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kramer65  staff     721 Feb 13 13:45 env.sh            <===
-rw-r--r--  1 kramer65  staff    1722 Feb 13 13:45 mvn.pom
... and some more files here
```

I checked whether go is installed and which version it is:

```
$ which go
/usr/local/bin/go
$ go version
go version go1.7.5 darwin/amd64
```

So go seems to be fine.

Does anybody have any idea how I can debug/solve this? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, never mind, I found it. The problem was that line endings where in DOS style.

So to recursively convert line endings to Unix I ran:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 dos2unix
```

and then tried building again. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem using by following instructions below. I don't know the reason, but I completely get rid of `brew` to make it run. (mac)

`` 1 install go(I used package)
2 git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
3 cd go-ethereum && git checkout tags/v1.8.2
4 run `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 dos2unix`(if you don't have dos2unix, you could brew one, it does not break anything.)
5 make geth
6 ln -s /path/to/origin/geth /path/to/target/geth ``

Then run `which geth` you could find your geth. Run `geth version` you can see your version.